# Replacing Threading.Timer with a custom async timer class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, timer, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to replace my old Threading.Timer code with something that can handle an async Function.  The reason I'm doing this is that you cannot pass a Threading.Timer an async function without making it an Async Sub, which I am to understand is a bad idea.

Code I wish to replace;

```
Dim SaveTimer as New Threading.Timer(AddressOf SaveToFile, Nothing, 1000 * 60 * 5, 1000 * 60 * 5)
```

SaveToFile is an async function, so I get an "The Task returned from this Async Function will be dropped, and any exceptions in it ignored. Consider changing it to an Async Sub so its exceptions are propagated" warning.

The purpose of this timer is to save the contents of the class it's in to a file every 5 minutes.  However, I also occasionally call SaveToFile manually and if I do I want to reset the timer.

With the Threading.Timer I would do this;

```
  Public Async Function ManuallySave As Tasks.Task
    SaveTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)
    Await SaveToFile
    SaveTimer.Change(1000 * 60 * 5, 1000 * 60 * 5)
  End Function
```

Now I know how to schedule something to be done with Tasks using Task.Delay but I'm not sure how to stop it and reset.

Here's my attempt at an async timer class;

```
Public Class AsyncTimer

  Private CancellationToken As New CancellationTokenSource
  Private DelegateAction As Action(Of Tasks.Task) = Nothing

  Public Sub New(DelegateAction As Action(Of Tasks.Task))
    Me.DelegateAction = DelegateAction
  End Sub

  Public Async Function StartTimer(Interval As Integer, Optional Repeat As Boolean = False) As Tasks.Task
    CancellationToken = New CancellationTokenSource
    Do
      Await Tasks.Task.Delay(Interval, CancellationToken.Token).ContinueWith(DelegateAction, CancellationToken.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled, TaskScheduler.Current)
    Loop Until Not Repeat OrElse CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested
  End Function

  Public Sub StopTimer()
    CancellationToken.Cancel()
  End Sub

End Class
```

What concerns me is that I call StopTimer, then shortly afterwards StartTimer, which replaces CancellationToken with a new instance.  I'm worried that before the cancellation of the token takes effect I'm overwriting it.

What is the solution to this?

I know the code is in VB but I understand C# just as well, so either as an answer would be fine.

EDIT1:  This needs to be thread-safe.  This is the cause of my concern.

Comment: Is this supposed to be thread-safe? Because it's not, and if it's not supposed to be, you don't need to worry about race conditions.

Comment: @I3arnon  It does need to be thread-safe unfortunately, is that possible? Edited the question to mention that.

Comment: @I3arnon I understand, but it does need to be thread-safe which is why I'm concerned about that specifically.

Comment: Well, it's not thread-safe at all. You need to use some synchronization constructs.

Comment: @I3arnon Appreciate the advice.  That's why I'm here though, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @I3arnon I believe async calls can't be used inside lock/Synclock though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timer ticks are queued to the thread-pool. You can use `async` and `await` there without problems. Make your tick function call an `async Task` function and throw away the resulting task. And document, why.

```
void TimerProc(...) {
 var task = TimerImpl();
 //throw away task
}

async Task TimerImpl() {
 try { MyCode(); }
 catch (Exception ex) { Log(ex); }
}
```

Note, that timer ticks can be delayed arbitrarily, they can execute concurrently and they can run after you have stopped the timer.

I don't see why you'd need to use async code anyway. You are already on the thread-pool so you don't have to unblock the UI. Writing to local disks does not benefit much from async IO. Maybe the answer is: Just use synchronous code here.

In order to guard against overwriting the `CancellationToken` you need to copy it to all places that uses it. Nothing should directly use the field.

Better yet, create a new instance of `AsyncTimer` instead of making it restartable. Avoid state mutation.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  First, I'm not sure what you mean by "Make your tick function call an async Task function and throw away the resulting task".  As in, assign the task to an object to start it and let the sub end?  Isn't that bad practice, regarding error handling and so on?  Whilst I know that writing to local disks might not warrant async, that's just one example of timer code I am considering replacing.  I also have timers that send web requests via a HttpClient, as another example.  With your last point, I'm not sure how to implement.

Comment: ...not sure how to implement.  The instance needs to be visible to two different subroutines, so say a private property of a class.  When I want to start the timer again I'd have to create a new instance over the existing one and have the same problem, except perhaps worse because I'm overwriting the whole instance rather than just the cancellation token.

Comment: I added code. You can throw away the task safely as long as you make the task itself handle errors. This is no different from synchronous task handlers: You have to catch errors.

Comment: Regarding the new instance: If you create a new instance the old one is still around. Same function, same token. It just isn't used anymore and does its work in the background until cancellation succeeds. Remember, that AsyncTimer is a reference type. Overwriting a AsyncTimer variable does nothing to the old object. Also note, that cancellation is always cooperative. You can never force an arbitrary function/task to end immediately.

Comment: Thanks appreciate that.  But I am under the impression errors that aren't handled are lost in that situation.  Obviously I try to catch all errors but we all make mistakes. Or am I wrong and an UnobservedTaskException event will still be raised by the TaskScheduler?

Comment: This event will be raised but the goal is to never have it raised. In timers and background threads you need a `catch(Exception)` around all other code in order to catch all errors as well as bugs. This is a safe pattern. How could an error still escape? It can't. (Except if the handler throws itself.)

Comment: Just to clarify, you are saying that if I created a new AsyncTimer object called TestTimer, started it, then stopped it, then overwrote the same object with TestTimer = new AsyncTimer() the old version of the object will still exist and be running and soon cancel?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you are unsure about reference semantics it is very important to research that. You *must* understand object references in C# to be successful.